# i need to retrieve data from database and use it in php if statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a system registration for courses and I am stuck with this problem I want the admin to have the ability to hide the form for sign up from the students( it's like making the system on or off) and when he wants to make it available again

The way I tried to solve is having a radio button in the admin page which passes in a database(with ajax)  the value 0 or 1 what I want is somehow to retrieve this value, store it to a php variable and use it in an if statement for example

html+ajax

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>OnClick Insert Radio Button value into Database using PDO in 
Jquery Ajax PHP | SoftAOX Tutorial</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> On Click Insert Radio Button Value into Database</h1>
<input type="radio" name="status" value= "1" >on<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="status" value= "0">off<br/><br/>

<h3 id="result"></h3>
<br/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
var status = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url:"insert.php"
method:"POST",
data:{status:status},
success: function(data){
$('#result').html(data);
}
});
});
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

//Insert Data
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename = "onlinecourse";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if (isset($_POST["status"])) {
        $query = "UPDATE CRS SET status =  (:status)";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                'status' => $_POST["status"]
            )
        );
        $count = $statement->rowCount();
        if ($count > 0) {
            echo "Data Inserted Successfully..!";
        } else {
            echo "Data Insertion Failed";
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

the file in which i want the if statement for redirection

```
<?php

session_start();
include('includes/config.php');

error_reporting(0);


if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
{   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');// change according timezone
$currentTime = date( 'd-m-Y h:i:s A', time () );
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  students where 
pincode='".trim($_POST['pincode'])."' && 
StudentRegno='".$_SESSION['login']."'");
$num=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

if($num>0)
{
 //statement for button

$_SESSION['pcode']=$_POST['pincode'];


if($status == "1") {
header("location:enroll.php"); //when system is on 
}
else {
    header("location:close.php"); //when system is off
}
}
else
{
$_SESSION['msg']="Error :Wrong Pincode. Please Enter a Valid Pincode !!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: ok thanks do you know any way to retrieve the value i want and use it in an if statement

Comment: You have got a syntax error in the second file. Missing `}`

Answer (score 1):

A **radio button**, when clicked, sends to the PHP script an string with the content of its property **value**.

**How to the data from a radio butom**:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value= "1" >on<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="status" value= "0">off<br/><br/>
```

The **radio**, like a **checkbox**, does not send anything to the PHP script when none of the options is selected.

You can do:

```
$status = $_POST['status'] ?? "0"; 
if($status = "1") {
    header("location:enroll.php"); //when system is on 
    exit;
} else {
    header("location:close.php"); //when system is off
    exit;
}
```

If you are not familiar with the **??** I used in the code, take a look at the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce). If your PHP version is < 7.0, you can use the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) instead.

Comment: yeah but this is checking if it is null ? i want to have the ability to turn it off whenever admin likes 

and correct me if i am mistaken but shouldn't use == instead of = ?

Comment: @daxternator I'm checking if it's null using the **null coalescing opetor** - **??**. It helps to save some lines of code. What the line `$status = $_POST['status'] ?? "0";` means is: if  `$_POST['status']` exists and is not null, assign its value to `$status`, else, assign `"0"` to `$status`. You can learn more about the ?? operator in the link I put in my answer.

Comment: yeah i understand but since i always i have a value it will always have this if statement true

Comment: If you will always have value in that field, you don't need that validation. You can just check its value directly: `if($_POST['status'] == "1") {...`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not much familiar with `ajax` but you can do something like this. Just think that there is a field named `statues_of_registration_form` and this field default in `0`(which is disabled) in signup_confirm_table.

Then in admin page you can let admin to change the status like this.

> admin.php

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <label> Change the visibility of the signup page</label>
   <select name="change_visibility">
    <option value="1">Show</option>
    <option value="0">Hide</option>
   </select>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Confirm</button>     
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']){

  $sql = "UPDATE signup_confirm_table SET statues_of_registration_form = '".$_POST['change_visibility']."';
  $result= $dbconnection->query($sql);

   if(isset($result)){

    echo "<script>
    alert('Form status updated');
    window.location='admin.php';
    </script>";
}else{
    if(mysqli_errno($con)){
        echo "Error:".mysqli_error($con);
    }  
 }

 }
?>
```

Now admin can set the `statues_of_registration_form` field to `0` or `1`. Next in your `signup.php` check the status before page load like below.

> signup.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT statues_of_registration_form FROM signup_confirm_table";
 $result= $dbconnection->query($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if( $row['statues_of_registration_form'] == 1 ) { ?>
 //if status of the form = 1 put your form here
  <form>
   <input type="text"/>
  </from>
 <?php 
}else{
  echo "<script>
        alert('Registration form disabled by the admin.');
        window.location='signup.php';
        </script>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note this is only a example .You are highly advised to use **prepared statements** in `sql`.Hope you can grab something from this. Thanks

Comment: @Dharman i have mentioned it in the answer. He should know how to use php

Comment: Yes, but why would you even suggest a buggy code and only put a small footnote at the end how to do it properly. It makes no sense